# Not able change MySQL password on the mac

Tags: mysql

I forget my MySQL password. and
I followed almost all the ways on the Google. 
But I'm still not able to change MySQL password. 
and I correctly wrote commands. 
What's the wrong with this? I really don't know. 
`ERROR 1064 (42000)` this error code getting me mad.

These are the commands I'm using:

```
mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> update user set password=password('xxxx') where user='root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('xxxx') where user='root'' at line 1
mysql> set password for 'root' = password('xxxx');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password('xxxx')' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: What about `set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('xxxx');`?

Answer (score 1):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html

MySQL is choking on you using password as a function.

The correct syntax is:

```
set password for 'root' = 'xxxx'
```

This will set the password for root@%  You might need to specify the host:

```
set password for 'root'@localhost = 'xxxx'
```

On modern MySQL this will encrypt the password for you.